# Change sent email copy's folder location with Microsoft Graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

The Mail REST API seems to only provide the option to set the SaveToSentItems property.  There is no option that I can find to change the actual folder location to a different folder entirely.

Exchange Web Services would be an option IF you were using EWS to send the email, but since it's Graph that's being used they cannot be combined in this scenario, AFAIK.

Is there a way that I'm overlooking?

Comment: I don't believe so but you should be able to move the item from Send Items to another folder after it's been created.

Comment: True, but my scenario is hoping to avoid having the items appear in Sent Items in the first place, due to some complex business logic